# Solution of triangles in Non-Euclidean geometry with restrictions

Tags: triangles, hyperbolic-geometry

In triangle $ABC, AB>AC$ . $D$ is a point on $AB$ such that $AD=AC$.

Prove that $\,\angle ADC=\frac{\angle B +\angle C}{2}$ and $\angle BCD=\frac{\angle C-\angle B}{2}$.

Solving this problem in Euclidean geometry is very easy. But how can it be solved with the following restrictions?

- Parallel postulate (i.e. properties of parallel lines ) cannot be used.
- Theorems proved using properties of parallel lines cannot be used.
- The problem has to be solved the way euclidean geometry problems are solved.    Cartesian Geometry cannot be used.

If this problem can be so solved, then please provide the solution. If not solvable, why cannot be?

Comment: Consider giving a description of the problem on the title and writing the problem in the main body of the question. Also have a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Michael I have done some edits.Is this question ok now?

Comment: A lot better now!

Comment: How do you solve problems "the way Euclidean geometry problems are solved" if you can't rely on the parallel postulate, which distinguishes Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry?

Comment: It's easy to see that if we only assume the sum of the angles of a triangle is $\pi$ then we can prove your statements. But only proof of the sum of angles fact I know uses parallel lines.

Comment: @baharampuri: That's because it is only true in Euclidean geometry. In hyperbolic geometry (which you get by negating the parallel postulate), the angle sum of a triangle is _not_ $\pi$.

Comment: @SaritDas: If you want a proof that doesn't use the parallel postulate, why do you keep inserting an [tag:euclidean-geometry] tag?

Comment: I don't see why this should hold in non-Euclidean geometry, and I think I have a counter-example using spherical geometry (see my answer below).

Comment: First I apologize for not stating my problem correctly.Actually the book(a high school book) where i found this problem, definition and properties of parallel lines were introduced later than where the problem is given.Since concepts of parallel lines were still not introduced, i thought it is required to prove these without using properties of parallel lines. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: I made an edit to make it look as simple as possible. Hope ok.  If not ok, feel free to put it back as before.

Comment: @HenningMakholm right I did not think of that while writing the comment, instead I was trying to show sum of triangles = $\pi$ implies parallel postulate :) I show that it is impossible without the parallel postulate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this holds in non-Euclidean geometry. Consider a sphere with $B$ at the South Pole $90^\circ \text{S}$, and $A$ and $C$ very near (and nearly on opposite sides of) the North Pole; say $A = 89^\circ \text{N}, 89^\circ \text{W}$ and $A = 89^\circ \text{N}, 89^\circ \text{E}$. Then $\angle C$ is nearly $180^\circ$ (if you fly due north along the 89th meridian east from $B$ to $C$, you only need to turn slightly to the left to continue from $C$ to $A$, with your closest approach to the North Pole coming on the Prime Meridian). Similarly, $\angle B$ is $178^\circ$, which is also nearly $180^\circ$. But $D$ is somewhere on the 89th meridian east and south of $C$—to be precise, very slightly due north of $87^\circ N, 89^\circ E$. Traveling the path $A \to D \to C$ requires performing a near-complete about-face at $D$, so $\angle ADC$ is very small. This is a counter-example to $\angle ADC = \frac{\angle B + \angle C}{2}$.